# How to get week number. (I have date)?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm currently working on a project that needs to find the week number of a given date.

Can you give me a code snippet for my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();


  now.set(Calendar.YEAR,2013);
  now.set(Calendar.MONTH,04);//0- january ..4-May
  now.set(Calendar.DATE, 04);

System.out.println("Current week of month is : " +
            now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));

System.out.println("Current week of year is : " +
            now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem with using this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int weekOfYear = ca.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: @letsgotim date variable takes Date format only, if its in String pls chk my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the info. :)